# WebGL view breaks page

Tags: webgl, elm

I'm trying to use `Graphics.WebGL`, but whenever I add a webGL Element to my page nothing appears, not even the other non-webGL elements I previously added. I'm using `elm-server`, and there's nothing in its console there to indicate that anything is wrong either -- theres just a blank page; it seems to have silently failed. I've swapped out the webGL code for a regular `collage`, which does show up, so as far as I know there isn't anything wrong with any of my other code.

Here's a few of the relevant parts of the code

```
     main = lift2 signalWrapper buttonSelected.signal frameRateSignal
```

buttonSelected.signal just keeps track of what button has been clicked in a non-webGL portion of the page. frameRateSignal is defined as

```
frameRateSignal : Signal Float
frameRateSignal = fps 25
```

Signal wrapper is

```
 signalWrapper signal time = flow right [buttons signal, glView time]
```

at this point if I swap `glView time` for `collage 500 500 [filled red (rect (50 + x) (50 + x))]` things still show up and work in the way one would expect. `glView` is defined as

```
glView time = webgl (50, 50) (scene time)
```

and scene is defined as

```
scene : Float -> [Entity]
scene time = [entity vertexShader fragmentShader fullScreenTriangle (uniforms time)]
```

The various components of that are

```
uniforms : Float -> {perspective : Mat4, camera : Mat4 }
 uniforms t = {perspective = makePerspective 45 1 0.01 100 ,
                 camera = makeLookAt (vec3 0 0 5) (vec3 0 0 0) (vec3 0 1 0)
              }

 fullScreenTriangle : [Triangle Vertex]
 fullScreenTriangle =
     let tovo  = vec3 1 1 0
         tovt  = vec3 0 0 0
         tovth = vec3 0 1 0
         ttvo  = vec3 1 0 0
         ttvt  = vec3 0 1 0
         ttvth = vec3 0 0 0
     in
     [
         (makeVertex tovo, makeVertex tovt, makeVertex tovth),
         (makeVertex ttvo, makeVertex ttvt, makeVertex ttvth)
     ]


 --shaders
 vertexShader : Shader { attr | position:Vec3, color:Vec3}
                       { unif | perspective:Mat4, camera:Mat4}
                       {vcolor:Vec3}
 vertexShader = [glsl|

     attribute vec3 position;
     attribute vec3 color;
     uniform mat4 camera;
     uniform mat4 perspective;
     varying vec3 vcolor;

     void main () {

         gl_Position = perspective * camera * vec4(position,1.0);
         vcolor = color;
     }
 |]

 fragmentShader : Shader {} {unif | perspective:Mat4, camera:Mat4} {vcolor:
 fragmentShader = [glsl|

     varying vec3 vcolor;
     void main () {

         gl_FragColor = vec4(vcolor,1.0);
     }
 |]
```

Sorry to post so much potentially irrelevant code, but I really have no idea where to go from here -- theres no visible error messages or anything to pursue.

Here's a [link to the full code](http://share-elm.com/sprout/539eb77de4b07afa6f982038).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look at your code and once I got it to compile, I found that the browsers development console had logged a usable error:

> uncaught exception: ERROR: 0:2: '' : No precision specified for (float)

The fragment shader requires you to define floating point precision. Once you define that, [your code gives some output](http://share-elm.com/sprout/539eb7d2e4b07afa6f982039).

Given that this error is shown in an unintuitive place and isn't warned about beforehand, I advise you to open an issue on the [library's GitHub page](https://github.com/johnpmayer/elm-webgl).